# mod_rewrite: remove www and redirect into folder if not already in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

First time here, and I'm a bit of a mod_rewrite and regex noob, so please let me know if I've missed anything. I've searched here and elsewhere all day but not found exactly what I need.

I'm looking for a set of RewriteConds and RewriteRules that will accomplish the following:

- remove the www, if present in URL
- redirect into a folder, if not already present in URL
- preserve the rest of the URL

I have a web app installed in a specific subfolder (we'll call it /webapp) which is configured to **require** no www on the url. It presents a stupid annoying message to the user if they include the www. I can dig into the app and reprogram that, but I'd like to handle that for the users through .htaccess and mod_rewrite, and simultaneously dump them into the folder, if they forget to type it, doing all of this with a 301 redirect.

For example, I'd like any of the following requests

```
http://www.mydomain.org/webapp/anything
http://www.mydomain.org/anything
http://mydomain.org/anything
```

To be redirected to

```
http://mydomain.org/webapp/anything
```

And obviously if a "correct" URL (one starting with `http://mydomain.org/webapp/`) is requested, it's not rewritten at all.

My best guess so far is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.org/$1 [R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webapp.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.org/webapp/$1 [R=302]
```

This seemed to work according to http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ but in practice, not so much.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself here: [BowlerHat](http://www.bowlerhat.co.uk/blog/mod_rewrite-tips-redirect-site-root-to-subdirectory/)

Looks like this:

```
# First just remove the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.org/$1 [L,R=301]

# Now redirect into the folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !webapp/ [NC]         # if the provided URI does not start with /webapp,
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.org/webapp/ [L,R=301]         # redirect user to /webapp/ root
```

I decided that if users try to visit mydomain.org/somethingsomething, just to send them to the root of the webapp, rather than /webapp/somethingsomething.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.org$
RewriteRule ^ mydomain.org/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webapp.*$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) mydomain.org/webapp/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No dice. Leaving off the 'http://' part means that 'www.mydomain.org' redirects to 'www.mydomain.org/home/accountname/webapp/'.  'mydomain.org' displays the index.html file, and 'mydomain.org/wrongpath' gives the 404 for wrongpath.